# Why am i getting 404 responses when rewriting if the htaccess and Laravel looks ok?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I'm having a problem doing internal rewrites with apache/htaccess and Laravel 5.1. The scenario is quite simple, I have some routes working on my app that needs to be rewritten to a more human/SEO/Customer friendly URL, my initial approach was simply rewrite them in htaccess as I did so many times.

However the, problem rises when I try to do it and it does not work at all, for example, if I have the url www.example.org/myroute/id and I want to rewritte to www.example.org/dummy-dummy-dummy-id.html

Normally i would do:

```
RewriteRule ^dummy-dummy-dummy-(\w+)\.html /myroute/$1
```

However when I follow this pattern with this laravel project I got a 404 error, i have been doing tests for some days and it does not matter what to do, it will always give you a 404 unless using the flag [R] wich redirects de request externally instead of the internal behaivor i need.

I have been using a dd() in the AppServiceProvider to see the details of the request the framework is getting and the URI it gets is allwas the friendly one (so the internal redirect does not reach the index.php) I have been looking at the mod_rewrite debug logs and looks like it is working fine matching the friendly url and doing and internal rewrite, but it never reaches the framework :(

this is the full htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
    php_value post_max_size 6M

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^local\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^beta\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^dummy-dummy-dummy-(\w+)\.html /myroute/$1

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

NOTE: I know that I can implement the friendly routes straight in the routes file of laravel, but I don't understand why this is not working so I would like to find out.

Comment: What is the `$4` in the rule?

Comment: @Dekel it was a mistake, already fixed ;) thanks for spot.

Comment: But it's the first pattern that you select. Why `$4`? use `$1`...

Comment: yes, you are right i was simplifying the question to its minimun expression, and the original rewrite has 4 captures, now it is fixed. Any way i have the same problem using something like this: RewriteRule ^white /black

Comment: And you still have problems there in this specific line?

Comment: The problem is not the line, is that the rewrite is not getting the index.php file so the internal redirecction is not working and the framework gets the prety route instead of the real route.